# Reading PV and depth simultaneously in hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-runtime, hololens

After one or two week using hololens, stream recorder solution(https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV) failed to work! It seems problem relates to capturing data from PV camera and other sensors(my hypothesis is AHAT sensor)
I also tried to do same work (capturing PV and AHAT) with other methods. I tried Unity (async and non-async methods {stop one while capturing the other) and putting functions in Update) and UWP (regular functions and multi-threading and ... ) but non of these methods worked!
Worst thing is that I can't even record or preview scene from hololens portal! ( the only one can see is the one wearing hololens!)

Comment: "can't even record or preview scene from HoloLens portal" -- Does it mean in Device Portal, you can see HoloLens 2 is connected with the status of Good, but there is no image/video when clicking Live Preview button? How about Screenshots and Video Records? Do you connect HoloLens 2 with USB cable or WIFI?

Comment: Status is good and device is connected, just after I click record/preview button in portal it opens window and shows streamed images but code throws an exception and app crashes. I use WIFI to connect but as far as I remmember had same problem with USB. even apps run localy on hololens do not work when requesting PV and depth.

Comment: For the OS version on the HL2 device, can update that here for us?   Asking the build, for example:  Build 20348.x    


Also, we do have some a fix around AHAT recording coming out soon  and in the dev channel currently:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-insider#fixes-improvements

Comment: build number is 20348.1513 . Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  This should be getting fixed soon.  The change is in the dev insider channel at moment for HoloLens 2 OS.   Here is tracking in meantime on the issue:  https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV/issues/133.   The workaround at moment is either go back to older OS build https://aka.ms/hololens2download/10.0.20348.1432  or waiting for future OS update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be getting fixed soon. The change is in the dev insider channel at moment for HoloLens 2 OS.

Here is tracking in meantime on the issue: github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV/issues/133.

The workaround at moment is either go back to older OS build aka.ms/hololens2download/10.0.20348.1432 or waiting for future OS update

Thanks!